# Generating word counts for dictionary

Tags: unix, dictionary

I have indexing process which takes documents from mysql database and puts them into solr.

I want to record number of occurrences of each word for spelling correction.

I could obviously just dump them all into one plaintext file as I go, then `sort | uniq -c` that file, and keep all words with counts above some N - is it the way to go, or is there some smarter way?

Answer (score 1):

In SOLR you have facets. You can try executing a facet search with the facet.field pointing to the field storing the text data of your interest. You can use facet.mincount to cut the output list on a certain frequency level. Make sure to set facet.zeroes=false to exclude any possible zeroes from the resulting frequency list.